# inner join selecting multiple id as name

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am really stuck, i have 2 tables with football match data:

#### team

```
id, name
```

#### fixture

```
id, hometeam, awayteam
```

I have done the following:

```
SELECT hometeam, awayteam, score, week FROM fixture
join team on fixture.hometeam = team.id;
```

basically the hometeam and awayteam are id numbers that relate to the team table, but i need to output these as the actual text name.

any help would be grately appreciated

thanks :)

Comment: dont think i understood the question right but from what i saw you're trying to do smth like: select fixture.hometeam as smth, team.name as somthelse, fixture.awayteam as smth33 from fixture left join team on fixture.hometeam = team.id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  th.name AS hometeam_name, ta.name AS awayteam_name, week, score
FROM    fixture
JOIN    team th
ON      th.id = fixture.hometeam
JOIN    team ta
ON      ta.id = fixture.awayteam
```

Comment: Quassnoi, you are a genious, thank you very much for your help, grately appreciated :)